# Attempting to delete multiple email messages in folder outside of inbox with Python and Exchangelib

Tags: python, python-3.x, exchangelib

I'm trying to delete all email messages in a folder outside of my account.inbox with Python 3 and exchangelib.

```
testFolder = account.root / 'Top of Information Store' / 'Test'    
emails = testFolder.all().order_by('-datetime_received')
for email in emails:
    email.delete()
    # FWIW
    #print(email.subject)
    #email.move(to_another_folder)
    #both work fine.
```

The above only prints all emails and their properties

I have also tried:

```
items=[]
testFolder = account.root / 'Top of Information Store' / 'Test'    
emails = testFolder.all().order_by('-datetime_received')
for email in emails:
    items.append(Message(folder=testFolder))
items.save()
items.delete()
```

The above hangs and gives a memory error:

```
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services.py", line 89, in _
get_elements
    response = self._get_response_xml(payload=payload)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services.py", line 171, in
_get_response_xml
    res = self._get_soap_payload(response=r, **parse_opts)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services.py", line 260, in
_get_soap_payload
    root = to_xml(response.iter_content())
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\util.py", line 365, in to_x
ml
    return parse(stream, parser=forgiving_parser)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\defusedxml\lxml.py", line 134, in parse
  elementtree = _etree.parse(source, parser, base_url=base_url)
  File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 3424, in lxml.etree.parse
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1857, in lxml.etree._parseDocument
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\util.py", line 340, in getv
alue
    res = b''.join(self._bytes_generator)
MemoryError
```

I'm not sure what else I should try, especially since the former works to move and print emails just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to collect the items first. This will consume a lot of memory, as you found out. Instead, you can call `.delete()` directly on the QuerySet. This will fetch only the item IDs and delete them in batches.

There is also an `.empty()` method which results in a call to the `EmptyFolder` service. This will delete all items in the folder without even fetching the IDs:

```py
testFolder.all().delete()
# Or even faster:
testFolder.empty()
```

Comment: Awesome! .empty() works perfectly! I hate to ask a question on an answer, but is there a way to do a .move() on a QuerySet?

Comment: There's no `.move()` on a queryset, but you can feed a queryset to `account.bulk_move()`.

Comment: I've tried going that route...but i'm doing it wrong. `qs = testFolder.all()` then `account.bulk_move(qs=, to_folder=newTestFolder)` and several other variations with no success, still receiving a memory error. This should probably be a new question...

Comment: You don't need the full item content, just the IDs:. This should reduce the memory pressure:  `account.bulk_move(qs= testFolder.all().only('id', 'changekey'), to_folder=newTestFolder)

Comment: You are super helpful! Thank you for your help and for developing this awesome package! This will save my team 200 work hours a month!

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad you found me and my software helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of delete try move to trash? or soft delete?